# how to apply a two-arg function to a sequence?

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence:

```
[a b c ...]
```

And a function `(f x y)`. I want to get this:

```
(f c (f b (f a 1)))
```

Etc.. How to do this?

Comment: [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce)

Comment: what about `1`? I can't find a way to do it with `reduce`. Can you give an example?

Comment: Click the link above for examples. The first example block shows a case of using `1` as an initial value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reduce, with a small adaptation:

```
(reduce #(f %2 %1) 1 [a b c])
```

Comment: @A.Webb Indeed, and the iterated applications of `f` take the sequence elements as first arg, not second.

Answer (score 2):

```
(reduce (fn [acc x] (f x acc)) 1 [a b c d])
```